UI Design for dynamically manage multiple groups of form elements
I'm developing a user interface where users need to dynamically manage multiple groups of form elements. These groups may vary in content and quantity. What user interface guidelines and patterns allow users to add new groups and easily remove unnecessary ones? I would like to clarify the best option for the delete and add buttons. The example of form is bellow. Any ideas and examples would be greatly appreciated!


Is there a limit to add groups? UI can be complex when the user reach over three groups and maybe fixing the header to the screen can help to reduce friction to the user, however it leaves narrow space on the screen to show the groups.

The main problem I see in your interface (not to mention the margins which are a nightmare ), is that you are working with information UI cards, but:

The total area occupied by the cards is not well defined
The visual limit of each card is so subtle that it goes unnoticed


Image source: dribbble
I would look for a graphical way to solve both points 1 and 2, and once defined it will be much easier for you to find the way to locate the action buttons and for the user to understand what actions they can perform.


Nice. Just to add on, I would also probably consider making the + add button blue to make it more noticable & it aligns with "positive" & your branding. I would also think about making the - red.

Oh hold on. In this situation I suggest using the trash icon instead of - as there is a possibility that users might mistake it as literally 'subtract'. Eg: $2000 - $2000 = Total value $4000.
